# Failing to reproduce specific Functional derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, functional-equations

I'm failing to reproduce an (indirect) result in a paper, namely

$${δF[g]\overδg(x,y,z)}={r^4\over\ell^5} $$
where $F[g]=\iiint \frac{2dxdydz}{\ell g(x,y,z)}    $ and $g(x,y,z)=-{\ell^2 \over r^2} $. Note that $\ell$ and $r$ do not depend on $x$, $y$ or $z$.

I'm not terribly familiar with functional derivatives, but it seems to me that this is a simple example, since no derivatives of $g$ appear in $F$, and hence, when $F$ is of the form $F[ρ]=\int f(ρ(\mathbf x)) d\mathbf x $, the following should hold[[e.g. from wiki]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Determining_functional_derivatives):
$${δF[f]\overδρ(\mathbf x)}=\frac {\partial f}{\partial ρ}$$
In this particular case, this gives
$$\begin{align}
{δF[g]\overδg(x,y,z)} &= \frac\partial{\partial g}\left(\frac {2}{\ell g(x,y,z)}\right)\\
&=- \frac {2} {\ell g^2(x,y,z)}\\
&=-2\frac {r^4} {\ell^5}
\end{align}$$

This isn't what the authors find. *The weird thing about this derivation is that the function derived with respect to, $g$, doesn't depend on its arguments but on $r$, and so does the functional.* It is as if I'm looking for a generalized relation for when $F$ of the form $F[ρ]=\int f(ρ(\mathbf x, r)) d\mathbf x $ rather than of the form $F[ρ]=\int f(ρ(\mathbf x)) d\mathbf x $, 
$${δF[f]\overδρ(\mathbf x, r)}=?$$

What am I doing wrong, and more generally, does this dependence on $r$ even make a difference?

---

[This](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9902121) is the paper I'm referring to, page 11, eq. (46) and line below. The calculation is the $AdS_4$ case, with $F \to S_{ct}=-\frac 2\ell\int dtdx_idx_i \sqrt{-γ}, g \to γ^{tt}=-\frac {\ell^2}{r^2}$ and  $\sqrt {-γ}=-(γ^{tt})^{-1}$. 

They claim $8πGT_{tt}=0=-2\frac {r^2}{\ell^3}+\frac 2{\sqrt{-γ}} \frac {δS_{ct}}{δγ^{tt}}$ from which I get the 'indirect' statement (at top): $\frac {δS_{ct}}{δγ^{tt}} =\frac {r^4}{ \ell^5}$

Comment: Is $r$ here a parameter, or is $r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$?

Comment: It's explicitly not just $x^2+y^2+z^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I) We have an answer up to an overall sign. From the $AdS_4$ Poincare bulk metric

$$ ds^2~=~ \frac{\ell^2}{r^2}dr^2 +\frac{r^2}{\ell^2}\left(-dt^2+dx^2_1+dx^2_2 \right) \tag{44}$$

in Ref. 1, we deduce that the 3D $\gamma_{\mu\nu}$ boundary metric is diagonal and

$$-\gamma_{tt}~=~ \gamma_{x_1x_1}~=~ \gamma_{x_2x_2}~=~\frac{r^2}{\ell^2}. \tag{A} $$

[This interpretation is further strengthen by comparing with eq. (17) for the $AdS_3$ case.] In other words,

$$\gamma_{\mu\nu}~=~\frac{r^2}{\ell^2}\eta_{\mu\nu},\tag{B} $$

where

$$\eta_{\mu\nu}~:=~{\rm diag}(-1,1,1).\tag{C}$$

II) Eventually, we want to vary the boundary metric $\gamma_{\mu\nu}$. To have a matrix close to a positive definite matrix, define

$$ M^{\mu}{}_{\nu}~:=~ \gamma^{\mu\lambda}\eta_{\lambda\nu}.\tag{D}$$

III) The counterterm action reads

$$ S_{ct}~=~\left(- \frac{2}{\ell}\right)\int \! dt ~dx_1 ~dx_2 ~\sqrt{-\gamma},\tag{46d} $$

where

$$ \gamma ~:=~\det\gamma_{\mu\nu}, \qquad 
\gamma^{-1} ~=~\det\gamma^{\mu\nu}.\tag{E} $$

IV) The [functional derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative)

$$\frac {\delta S_{ct}}{\delta \gamma^{tt}}\tag{F} $$

is proportional to

$$ \left(- \frac{\ell}{2}\right)\frac{2}{\sqrt{-\gamma}} \frac {\delta S_{ct}}{\delta \gamma^{tt}} 
~=~\frac{2}{\sqrt{-\gamma}} \frac {\partial \sqrt{-\gamma}}{\partial \gamma^{tt}}
~=~\frac{1}{\gamma} \frac {\partial \gamma}{\partial \gamma^{tt}}
~=~ -\frac{1}{\gamma^{-1}} \frac {\partial \gamma^{-1}}{\partial \gamma^{tt}}$$ 
$$~=~-\frac {\partial \ln \det M}{\partial \gamma^{tt}}
~=~-\frac {\partial {\rm tr}\ln  M}{\partial \gamma^{tt}}
~=~-{\rm tr} \left( M^{-1}\frac {\partial M}{\partial \gamma^{tt}}\right)$$
$$~=~-\gamma_{\mu\nu}\frac {\partial \gamma^{\nu\mu}}{\partial \gamma^{tt}}
~=~-\gamma_{tt}~\stackrel{(A)}{=}~ \frac{r^2}{\ell^2}, \tag{G}$$

and hence

$$\frac 2{\sqrt{-\gamma}} \frac {\delta S_{ct}}{\delta \gamma^{tt}} 
~\stackrel{(G)}{=}~-\frac {2r^2}{\ell^3},\tag{H} $$

which is precisely the **opposite** of what is needed to make

$$ 8\pi G T_{tt}~=~-\frac {2r^2}{\ell^3}+\frac 2{\sqrt{-\gamma}} \frac {\delta S_{ct}}{\delta \gamma^{tt}} \tag{46a} $$

zero. We would be interested in learning the culprit of the missing sign. It might be a matter of conventions.

References:

1. V. Balasubramanian and P. Kraus, *A Stress Tensor for Anti-de Sitter Gravity,* [Commun.Math.Phys. 208 (1999) 413](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s002200050764), [arXiv:hep-th/9902121](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9902121).

Comment: Thank you. I like the way you completely circumvent $r$ in the derivation. I'll let you know if I find the missing minus sign